# multiple with jquery auto complete in rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins

I want to generate a comma separated auto complete list in my rails application.With my code I am able to achieve only simple auto complete. Please let me know the tweaking in the code to be done so that comma separated auto complete is implemented.

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var string1=" ";
console.log("string1 before ="+string1);
string1=names.toString();
var arrayOfStrings=new Array();
arrayOfStrings = string1.split(",");
console.log("arrayOfStrings is array=="+Array.isArray(arrayOfStrings));
console.log("arrayOfStrings ==" + arrayOfStrings);
$("#release_tester_tokens").autocomplete({
                source :arrayOfStrings,
                matchContains: true,
        multiple: true,     
        autoFill: true
    });
});
```

my names come from my view file:

```
:javascript
   names = #{Release.user_names.to_json}
```

My .rb file

```
def self.user_names
  @@user_names||= User.all.map(&:name)

 end
```

The console output on trying to log names from the .js file:

```
names===aaloshious,aarul,aaziz,abaher,abain,abaltean



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>TestCase Manager - </title>
  <link href="/stylesheets/general.css?1320900943" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/tables.css?1322133776" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/pagination.css?1320900943" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/forms.css?1320900943" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/tooltips.css?1320900943" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/widgets.css?1320900943" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.treetable.css?1320900943" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.autocomplete.css?1324378307" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/stylesheets/formtastic.css?1320900943" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/formtastic_changes.css?1320900943" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css?1320900943" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.tooltip.css?1320900943" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.tokeninput.js?1324370104" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/swfobject.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.rest_in_place.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/jquery.dimensions.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.treetable.js?1323073747" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.pageless.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.autoresize.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.autocomplete.js?1324378273" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.ba-bbq.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.tooltip.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.bgiframe.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1325665117" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="page">
        <div id="flash_messages">
        </div>
        <div id="loading_indicator" style="display: none;">
          <div>

            <p class="flash_message">Loading</p>  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
          <h1></h1>
          <!-- - testers = User.joins(:role).where('roles.name' => 'Tester') -->
<!-- -testers=User.find_by_sql("select * from users where id in(select user_id from user_role_assignments where role_id in (select id from roles where name like 'Tester'))") -->
<!-- - leads = User.joins(:role).where('roles.name' => 'Test Lead') -->
<!-- TODO: THis should be put in the model. -->
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/releases" class="formtastic release" id="new_release" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="h1uDwnpSkP3fxLbkGJP6HVm/zvkwDM1cg5aWzbL3Ic0=" /></div>
  <table class='grid full'>

    <tr>
      <td class='grid full_panels' style='width: 50%'>
<div class="section"><table><tr><td class="tc_left"></td><td class="tc_center" colspan="2"><h2>Edit Release Info</h2><ul class="section_menu"></ul></td></tr><tr class=""><td class="sc_left"></td><td class="sc_center">      
        <fieldset class="inputs"><ol><li class="string required" id="release_name_input"><label for="release_name">Name<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label><input id="release_name" maxlength="255" name="release[name]" type="text" /></li>
        <li class="select required" id="release_owner_input"><label for="release_owner_id">Owner<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label><select id="release_owner_id" name="release[owner_id]"><option value="1240" selected="selected">sramya</option></select></li>
        <li class="select required" id="release_project_input"><label for="release_project_id">Project<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label><select id="release_project_id" name="release[project_id]"><option value="1">silver</option>

        <option value="2" selected="selected">molybdenum</option></select></li>
        <li class="string optional" id="release_description_input"><label for="release_description">Description</label><input id="release_description" maxlength="255" name="release[description]" type="text" /></li>
        <li class="string optional" id="release_start_at_input"><label for="release_start_at">Start</label><input class="datepicker" id="release_start_at" name="release[start_at]" type="text" /></li>
        <li class="string optional" id="release_end_at_input"><label for="release_end_at">End</label><input class="datepicker" id="release_end_at" name="release[end_at]" type="text" /></li>
        <li class="select optional" id="release_status_input"><label for="release_status">Status</label><select id="release_status" name="release[status]"><option value=""></option>
        <option value="NOT-STARTED" selected="selected">NOT-STARTED</option>

        <option value="IN-PROGRESS">IN-PROGRESS</option>
        <option value="COMPLETE">COMPLETE</option>
        <option value="CANCELED">CANCELED</option></select></li>
        </ol></fieldset>
<fieldset class="buttons"><ol><li class="commit"><input class="create" id="release_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" /></li>
</ol></fieldset>        <div class='submit_alternatives'>
          or
          <a href="/releases/new">Cancel</a>

        </div>
</td><td class="sc_right"></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="scb_left"></td><td class="scb_center"></td><td class="scb_right"></td></tr></table></div>      </td>
      <td class='grid full_panels'>
<div class="section"><table><tr><td class="tc_left"></td><td class="tc_center" colspan="2"><h2>Assign Testers</h2><ul class="section_menu"></ul></td></tr><tr class="table_wrapper"><td class="sc_left"></td><td class="sc_center"><table>
  <th>Name</th>
  <label for="release_tester_tokens">Testers</label>
  <input id="release_tester_tokens" name="release[tester_tokens]" size="30" type="text" />

  <!-- /= form.autocomplete_field_tag 'tester_name', :data-autocomplete=>"releases_autocomplete_user_name_path" -->
  <tr>
    <td>aaloshious</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aarul</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaziz</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="3" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abaher</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="4" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abain</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="5" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abalteanu</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="6" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abencz</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="7" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abennett</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="8" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abenoy</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="9" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aberkovich</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="10" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abhose</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="11" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abirchall</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="12" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abouchard</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="13" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abrezinov</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="14" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aburden</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="15" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aburt</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="16" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acar</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="17" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acarver</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="18" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acase</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="19" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acatana</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="20" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>achandel</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="21" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>achandrasekaran</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="22" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>achaudhary</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="23" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>achen</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="24" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acheng</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="25" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acohen</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="26" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acompagnoni</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="27" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aczegledi</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="28" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>adandy</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="29" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>adavoren</td>
    <td><input id="release_tester_ids_" name="release[tester_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="30" /></td>

  </tr>
</table>
</td><td class="sc_right"></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="scb_left"></td><td class="scb_center"></td><td class="scb_right"></td></tr></table></div>      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<!-- /=will_paginate @testers -->
<!-- /-@names=["sramya","scharron"] -->
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
     names = ["aaloshious","aarul","aaziz","abaher","abain","abalteanu","abencz","abennett","abenoy","aberkovich","abhose","abirchall","abouchard","abrezinov","aburden","aburt","acar","acarver","acase","acatana","achandel","achandrasekaran","achaudhary","achen","acheng","acohen","acompagnoni","aczegledi","adandy","adavoren","adaya","adehili","adesai","adevrieze","adewhurst","adweb","aedwards","aelsom","sramya"]
  //]]>
</script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1320900941" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1325665117" type="text/javascript"></script>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar"></div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>

      <div id="footnotes_holder"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="footer_inner">
        <dl class="quick_links">
          <dt><strong>Portal Navigation</strong></dt>
          <dd>
            <ul>

              <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="/ics">ICs</a></li>
              <li><a href="/reports">Reports</a></li>
            </ul>
          </dd>
        </dl>

        <dl class="copy">
          <dt><strong>TestCase Manager Portal</strong></dt>
          <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>Signed in as sramya (TesterTest Lead)</li>
                <li><a href="/user/sign_out">Sign out</a></li>
            </ul>

          </dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out here.
Thanks,
Ramya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is formated below with demo of Autocompelete code. You can test it seperately.  Autocomplete is triggered after the click into input box. Type 'J' It will show the months below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
 ul li{ list-style-type:none;}
</style>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var string1 = "January,Febrauary,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December";
    console.log("string1 before =" + string1);
    var arrayOfStrings = string1.split(",");
    console.log("arrayOfStrings is array==" + Array.isArray(arrayOfStrings));
    console.log("arrayOfStrings ==" + arrayOfStrings);
    $("#release_tester_tokens").click(function(){showAutocomplete(arrayOfStrings);});
});  
function showAutocomplete(arrayOfStrings) { 
    $("#release_tester_tokens").autocomplete(arrayOfStrings,{     
        width: 320,
        max: 4,
        highlight: false,
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator: " ",
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 300
    }); 
    };  
</script>
</head>
<body>
Month:<input type="text" id="release_tester_tokens" name="release_tester_tokens" value=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

In this autocomplete plugin, Array should be passed as a first argument. Second argument will be settings.

Comment: Hi Umesh Thanks a lot for answering me. The problem in my set up is that the array is in the form of Json. Hence only if I give it with the source:Array option its working.

Comment: What is in the JSON file ? Provide the structure of sample JSON. So, I can guide you properly :)

Comment: Hi Umesh I have edited my question with the structure of the JSON. Also this is the error I am getting on typing a character in the text box if I pass array as the first argument this.source is not a function
_search()jquery...0900941 (line 5216)
value = "a"
search()jquery...0900941 (line 5209)
value = "a"
event = Object { originalEvent=Event keydown, type="keydown", more...}
(?)()jquery...0900941 (line 5014)
[Break On This Error] this.source( { term: value }, this.response );

Comment: Here you require to add value of names "aaloshious,aarul,aaziz,abaher,abain,abaltean" into string1. How will you do it?

Comment: Hi Umesh, I converted names into string using toString and stored it in string1.string1=names.toString();

Comment: Ramya, Autocomplete occurs when user enter something on textbox. I am unable to guess what the problem is. Show your HTML also !

Comment: Hi Umeash,I have edited the question to include the html. I am getting the error on typing a character in the text box if I give array as the first argument. If I give it in source I am not getting any error.